# How can I get the community label from a Google Plus api post on my public profile?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

For my website, I'm using my public Google+ posts to fill my blog page. Currently I have it hardcoded saying 'Shared Publicly' but I would like to show for the ones that are posted to a public community to show Shared on Magikarp Appreciation Society (as an example).

On my site, in the javascript console is the list of posts in object. None of them have a property that has any value relating to what it is shared on.
http://master5o1.com/Posts

Could someone point me in the right direction for finding what a post is posted to?

Answer (score 1):

The Google+ API provides access to publicly shared posts, only. I would recommend using a unique hashtag to mark your blog posts, and then performing an [activities.search API call](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) with that hashtag to find the posts you want to surface on your blog.

You can also embed specific posts directly onto your website with the new [Google+ Embedded Posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/) feature, which would allow your readers to +1 or comment directly on the Google+ post from your blog.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I was trying to say. In my list of public posts includes the my posts on public communities. I want to label these posts as what community they were posted on.

Comment: There's currently no API support for Google+ Communities, and thus no way to discover where a post was shared.