# Extracting data/information from google plus community page to json file

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-plus, information-extraction

i am tying to extract information from a google plus community page. 
In a json file format it would help me to analyze some social behavior.

Actually, i tried it in the chrome browser in developer mode, after i analyzed the html structure of the community page.

I would like save it in a format like:

```
[ {author: "name", post: "post", comments: [{commentator: "cmm", comm: "comment"}]}]
```

I tried with this javascript:

```
        // saving all the posts in the posts-array
    var posts = document.getElementsByClassName("V2SCpf vCjazd")
    var docLength = posts.length

    var json = []

    // pushing all the text in the json array
    for(var i = 0; i < docLength; i++){
        json.push(posts[i].innerText)
    }

    // new array for extracting
    var newArray = new Array();

    // getting the lines
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { 
        newArray[i] = json[i].split('\n'); 
    } 

    for (var x = 0; x < docLength; x++){
        for (var y = 0; y < newArray[x].length; y++){

            let n = newArray[x][y]

            if(n.length == 0){
               continue;      
            } else {
                newArray[x][y]
            }
        }
    }

//looking for my data
    newArray
```

finally i got something like that, when i use a save function:

```
[
    [
        "",
        "Authors name",
        "Discussion",
        "",
        "",
        "2h",
        "Comment from author",
        "oecd.org",
        "no plus ones",
        "no comments",
        ""
```

My question: how can i bring all these data into my json file format?
Thank you.

Comment: The data returned by the Google API is Json format.

Comment: Hi thank you. But i researched and not found a google API for getting this data. Here a related post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762248/how-can-i-get-the-community-label-from-a-google-plus-api-post-on-my-public-profi